# How to Load a MKMapView in Another View Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, performance, mkmapview

As the title states, I am trying to load a `MKMapView` in separate view controller and then perform a push segue (from the `FirstViewController` to the `MapViewController`) when it is done. Here is my code for initializing the `MapViewController`:

```
//initiate the map view controller
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

MapViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapViewController"];
viewController.mapDelegate = self;

//force -viewDidLoad to be called
[viewController view];
```

This works fine, and `-viewDidLoad` is called. From it I set up my `MKMapView` and set its delegate to self. The `FirstViewController` triggers a segue to the second view controller when a delegate method is called from `MapViewController`:

```
//push to the map view controller
if(self.navigationController){
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapController animated:YES];
}
```

The problem is that when I wait until the `MKMapView`'s delegate method `-mapViewWillStartLoadingMap` to call the callback the push segue is never initiated. I have tried to force the `MKMapView` to load via `[mapview setNeedsDisplay]`, but this produces no results.

**How can I force the MKMapView to load in a different View Controller?**

Comment: Are you sure that you actually added the map view to the view controller that's being pushed?

Comment: Yes I'm sure that it is actually added.

Comment: Gosh!! From where do you get such requirements !. Did you use `prepareForSegue`

Comment: I did not use `prepareForSegue`. I have these requirements because, in addition to loading the map, I have to load about 800 pins with custom images on each one. I would rather have a nice loading screen than have the user watch the pins slowly populate the map.

Comment: I would reconsider that. 800 pins is insanely bad UX. Have you considered doing the regular way and do map clustering with those pins?

Comment: The pins are distributed world-wide on the map, but still I agree it is bad UX in this stage in development. I'll do some research on it.